# Ready event of SVG text element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom-events

Is there any way to know that the SVG text element has completed all the rendering steps on the page?

For example, when setting the text to a different font family, the text first changes its size, then changes its appearance to a new font,
then it changes its size again (it even happens several times), then it becomes sharper.

These steps are different in different browsers and depend on many processes, for example, on the font fallback and loading a new font file.

Without knowledge, when the text element has finished its preparations, it is not possible to obtain the actual dimensions of the text element (width and height), since at any time they can be adjusted by the browser for better look or something else. Without this event, it is not possible to do normal work with text in online editors built on the basis of SVG.

I have to make a long timer in the hope that by the time it is triggered the text will be ready. But this is too long when there are many text elements, if we need to set their parameters in series, and to have the previous result of text sizes before the next step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem boils down to being able to know when a particular FontFace has loaded.

For this, you can use the [FontFace API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API).

For the fonts that are declared in CSS and used directly at page load, the Document exposes a [`fonts.ready`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/ready) property which is a Promise that will get resolved when all the fonts used at DOMContentLoaded will be ready:

```js
// only for demo (avoids cache)
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = `@font-face {
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light';
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/shadowsintolight/v7/UqyNK9UOIntux_czAvDQx_ZcHqZXBNQzdcD55TecYQ.woff2?t=${ Math.random()}") format('woff2');
}`;
document.head.append(style);
// end only for demo

const text = document.querySelector('text');
console.log('before', text.getComputedTextLength());

document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
  console.log('after', text.getComputedTextLength());
});
```

```css
text {
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <text y="60">Hello world</text>
</svg>
```

If you have fonts that you wish to add after the page has loaded, then you can use the [`document.fonts.load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/load) method:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('text');
document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
  console.log('font.ready fires too soon');
});

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.fonts.load("30px 'Shadows Into Light'")
    .then(() => {
      console.log('at font load', text.getComputedTextLength());
    });
  text.classList.add('use-font');
  console.log('before', text.getComputedTextLength());
}, {once: true});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light';
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/shadowsintolight/v7/UqyNK9UOIntux_czAvDQx_ZcHqZXBNQzdcD55TecYQ.woff2") format('woff2');
}
text.use-font {
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light';
}
text { font-size: 30px; }
```

```html
<svg>
  <text y="60">Click to change the font</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you much! Text is really change its sizes multiple times only when a new font is loading. When the font is allready loaded, there is no size changes, just switching into this font.